# How to bypass reqular expression validation for specific characters

Tags: java, regex

We use a library which uses the regular expression

```
Pattern.compile("^\\w+(\\.\\w+)*$")
```

which is used to validate a string .
For example `abc.xyz` is valid string and it passes through the validation.
As a workaround for another issue i need provide the string as   `abc.xyz,efg.ghi`, which obviously does not get past the regex validation.Is there a way to make this string pass through the validation and if yes, how ?
PS: I tried using the escape sequences `abc.xyz\\,efg\\.ghi`. It did not work .

Comment: You will have to change regex.Your regex does not accept `,` as of now

Comment: Just split your string on ',' and then validate using the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Just put comma and dot inside a character class.

```
Pattern.compile("^\\w+([,.]\\w+)*$");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kZ0nR0/1)

Comment: Thanks but thats not an option as the pattern is part of a external library

Comment: Regular expression is not in my control.. an external library does the validation on the string i pass. But i need the string in this format  abc.xyz,efg.ghi to pass through that regex validation .

Comment: @user68883 that i fear is not possible

Comment: @user68883 Then, you have two choices: edit the library (in case you have access to the source), or **split the string by commas** and iterate on an array containing all fragments.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands now, you can't pass in , characters. However, if there really is no way to change the library (e.g. proprietary), you can abuse Java's String cache + reflection to change the String literal before the proprietary class is loaded.